# Why I have different space between some par?

Tags: xetex, paragraphs, line-spacing

If I enable the ban of hanging rows:

```
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
```

for some reason, the distance between several paragraphs begins to change.

[image]
[image]

Especially to make it noticeable, I increased the distance between the lines. This is the same document, but as you can see, the distance between the paragraphs is different. How to make it the same, respectively, the distance between the lines.

If I do not specify

```
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
```

everything is normal

Comment: TeX  starts the first line and ends the _last_ line of a page _always_  at the same height. This is only possible if there are some glue which can be stretched to get this behaviour. This is the reason why sometimes the space between paragraphs varies (\parskip). If you do not like it then use `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: @Herbert, thanks. I initially guessed what the problem was, but I did not know how to solve it. The search for "vertical text align" on the page did not yield anything.

Comment: Do not search on-site, but using the search engine of your choice. That's much more effective (for the next time).

Comment: @Игорь - I got 1162 hits searching "vertical text align".  Perhaps you meant "anything useful".

Comment: Perhaps the reason that I was looking in Russian. Results related to align in tables.